# Scene Builder's CSS Analyzer not working on Windows

Tags: css, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a problem with Scene Builder's CSS Analyzer but only on Windows.

Here is what I have done in both environments (Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04):

- I have created a new FXML file
- I have added a anchor pane and set a styleSheet
- In this anchor pane I have added a Label. I also set the styleSheet here (although this is probably not necessary).

The Label does show the style contained in the styleSheet (I have changed the Font Size and color).

I then open Scene Builder's CSS Analyzer and select the Label.

On Ubuntu, in the column "styleSheets", I do see what I have set in my styleSheet file. That's fine.

On Windows7, the column "styleSheets" is empty. Only the column "Defaults" is filled.

However, both Ubuntu and Windows are reflecting what is set in the styleSheet file.
I don't understand why, on windows, CSS Analyzer doesn't show some content in the "styleSheets" column. Is that a bug?

This is very annoying because it prevents from seeing which CSS rule will be applied.

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I works fine on Mac as well. Can you file an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues?status=new&status=open)?

Comment: Done here: https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/scenebuilder/issues/170/scene-builders-css-analyzer-not-working-on