# CSS Analyzer @SceneBuilder version 20 does not show changes coming from stylesheet\inline styles (it shows only the defaults)

Tags: scenebuilder, gluon

I have been working long time with scene builder 8.5.0 (due to my project being on java 8).

I recently tried to work with scene builder 20. Everything works well except for the CSS analyzer pane (which turned to be super usefull on my projects).

The problem:
The analyzer does not show properties actual value that has been overidden by css\inspector and only shows the defaults (the actual changes are taking effect in scene builder itself, its just the analyzer that does not show them)

In the below fxml file, I have a label with CSS rule applied on it coming from style sheet.
The class is `header-label` and it sets the `-fx-text-fill` property to be purple.

I have opened that fxml in scene builder v8.5.0 with css analyzer, and I am getting the below (expected) state:
[image]

I have opened the very same fxml (with the same CSS) with scene builder 20 and I am getting the below state:
[image]

Note that in the analyzer it does not show either the purple color (coming from the style sheet) nor the red color that was applied in the inline sytle...

I have tried to search and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566970/scene-builders-css-analyzer-not-working-on-windows). The issue referenced there is no longer active.

Am I missing something ? Any ideas ?